# Cannot find module path

Tags: macos, go, path

I have a MacBook M1 Air and installed the beta Go version "go1.16beta1 darwin/arm64"

I am trying to follow an online MIT course online and ran the following commands found here (https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.824/labs/lab-mr.html)

```
git clone git://g.csail.mit.edu/6.824-golabs-2020 6.824

cd 6.824/src/main

go build -buildmode=plugin ../mrapps/wc.go
```

I then got this error:

```
build command-line-arguments: cannot find module for path _/Users/MYUSERNAME/6.824/src/mr
```

I think this issue may have to do with relative imports specifically the importing of "../mr" in wc.go but I am unsure of the solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: check this [post](https://medium.com/rungo/everything-you-need-to-know-about-packages-in-go-b8bac62b74cc)

Comment: **Never** use relative imports. **Never** call `go build` with files as arguments. **Always** use modules.

Comment: The lab setup is quite poor, and does not follow standard practices. Starting with the official docs like [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) will help you understand the build process.

Comment: @Volker only a sith deals in absolutes.